# Retrieving options page value breaks when disabled

Tags: php, wordpress, settings

I've created an setting page for my custom plugin, in this setting page there's a checkbox.

The options name in the database is my_options_setting, the value is empty when the checkbox is unchecked. When checked the value becomes a:1:{s:15:"css";s:1:"1";}

My code is below, but when the options is disabled it breaks my code. As far as my understanding there shouldn't be an else statement because the empty else statement gives the same value as none.

What am I missing?

```
$options = get_option( 'my_options_setting');

if ( $options['css'] == '1' ) {

    function load_admin_styles() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom', CSS_PATH . 'custom.css');
    }
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_admin_styles' );
}
```

Comment: why not having else statement ? in case its necessary... i would use `if ( $options && $options['css'] == '1' )`

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that `$options` is an array, but if it doesn't exist, then the default return value of [`get_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) is used, which by default is `false`. Fortunately, the second parameter of `get_option()` allows you to override the default value:

```php
$options = get_option( 'my_options_setting', array() );
```

You could also introduce some redundancy by testing that `$options` is an array:

```php
if ( ! is_array( $options ) ) {
    $options = array();
}
```